# read/write clipboard data google chrome

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, clipboard

Пишу расширения для Google Chrome.Пытаюсь записать\считать содержимое буфера.
Делаю это примерно так:

```
 chrome.tabs.executeScript( {
     code: "document.addEventListener('copy', function(e){ var data=e.clipboardData.getData('text'); alert(data);});"   
  })
```

Этот способ не работает. Возможно, тут где-то ошибка?
Так же наткнулся на вот такой API https://developer.chrome.com/apps/clipboard . Возможно теперь события буфера можно ловить только с помощью него?
Пример отсюда https://www.w3.org/TR/clipboard-apis/#the-copy-action говорит, что мой способ должен работать. В чем проблема, не пойму.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном исполнении `chrome.tabs.executeScript` выполняет код синхронно. Вы вешаете обработчик события, которое может произойти когда-то в будущем, поэтому такой вариант не подойдет.

`chrome.clipboard` API доступно пока только для dev-ветки браузера, и я бы пока не рекомендовал использовать.

Так как буфер обмена доступен глобально, его содержимое можно получить из background скрипта, воспользовавшись сниппетом:

```js
function getClipboard() {
    var textEl = document.createElement('textarea');
    document.body.appendChild(textEl);
    textEl.focus();

    document.execCommand('paste');
    var value = textEl.value;
    document.body.removeChild(textEl); 

    return value; 
}
```

Не забудьте добавить `clipboardRead` в секцию `permissions` в файле manifest.json

P.S. На тему работы с буфером обмена есть пример расширения [Clipboard History](https://github.com/Deliaz/clipboard-history)